# Flexbox table with colspan (flex-grow)

Tags: html, sass, flexbox

I'm creating a huge data-table using flexbox, and I have a problem aligning columns that are "colspanned" using `flex-grow`.

### **Why flexbox?**

Because of the application spec. I need 3 tables, one on top of another, with fixed `<thead>` of each table which are fixed at the top of the screen until I scroll passed the table, and then fixed `<thead>` of the second table, etc... `position: sticky;` seemed like a great solution, except it does not work with tables.
Therefore flexbox.

### **The problem**

Since `<thead>` has 3 rows and colspans in 1 row, it was relatively easy for me to adjust the layout when all the columns from `<tbody>` use `flex-grow: 1;`. The problem was when I wanted to set the first and last column to some other width.

### **The question**

How do I set the `flex-grow` to colspanned columns if I would like the **Process ID** column to be `flex-grow: 2;` and **Status message** column to be `flex-grow: 4;`? The columns from the row above that are colspanned always get miss-aligned...

Codepen link:
Working example with `flex-grow: 1;`
https://codepen.io/vedranjaic/full/gGJMEx/
*(you can click on the button in the table title to collapse the menu)*

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="content">

        <nav class="main-menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Nav link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Nav link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Nav link 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <div class="table-flex table-process-error">

            <div class="table-thead ">
                <div class="table-row table-header">
                    <div class="table-row-item">
                        <h3 class="table-title"><a href="#" class="btn btn-default main-menu-toggle"><i class="icon fa fa-bars"></i></a> Error processes</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.table-row -->
                <div class="table-row">
                    <div class="table-row-item flex-grow-4">Context</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item flex-grow-4">Process Session</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item flex-grow-3">Execution</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item flex-grow-1">Info</div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.table-row -->
                <div class="table-row">
                    <div class="table-row-item">Process ID</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">Source</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">Schedule</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">Context</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">Session ID</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">Period From</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">Period To</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">Action</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">Start</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">End</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">Duration</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">Status message</div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.table-row -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.table-thead -->

            <div class="table-tbody">
                <div class="table-row">
                    <div class="table-row-item">PROCID123</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">N/A</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">DAY</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">N/A</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">6</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">27.9.2017</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">28.9.2017</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item"><input type="checkbox"></div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">13.10.2017 00:00</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">13.10.2017 01:58</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">00:01:58</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus, dolor!</div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.table-row -->

                <div class="table-row">
                    <div class="table-row-item">PROCID123</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">N/A</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">DAY</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">DEV</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">6</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">27.9.2017</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">28.9.2017</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item"><input type="checkbox"></div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">13.10.2017 00:00</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">13.10.2017 01:58</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">00:01:58</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus, dolor!</div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.table-row -->
                <div class="table-row">
                    <div class="table-row-item">PROCID123</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">N/A</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">DAY</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">DEV</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">6</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">27.9.2017</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">28.9.2017</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item"><input type="checkbox"></div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">13.10.2017 00:00</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">13.10.2017 01:58</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">00:01:58</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus, dolor!</div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.table-row -->
                <div class="table-row">
                    <div class="table-row-item">PROCID123</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">N/A</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">DAY</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">DEV</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">6</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">27.9.2017</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">28.9.2017</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item"><input type="checkbox"></div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">13.10.2017 00:00</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">13.10.2017 01:58</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">00:01:58</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus, dolor!</div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.table-row -->
                <div class="table-row">
                    <div class="table-row-item">PROCID123</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">N/A</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">DAY</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">DEV</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">6</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">27.9.2017</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">28.9.2017</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item"><input type="checkbox"></div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">13.10.2017 00:00</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">13.10.2017 01:58</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">00:01:58</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus, dolor!</div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.table-row -->
                <div class="table-row">
                    <div class="table-row-item">PROCID123</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">N/A</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">DAY</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">DEV</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">6</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">27.9.2017</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">28.9.2017</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item"><input type="checkbox"></div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">13.10.2017 00:00</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">13.10.2017 01:58</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">00:01:58</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus, dolor!</div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.table-row -->
                <div class="table-row">
                    <div class="table-row-item">PROCID123</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">N/A</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">DAY</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">DEV</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">6</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">27.9.2017</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">28.9.2017</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item"><input type="checkbox"></div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">13.10.2017 00:00</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">13.10.2017 01:58</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">00:01:58</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus, dolor!</div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.table-row -->

            </div>
            <!-- /.table-tbody -->

        </div>
        <!-- /.table-flex -->
        <div class="table-flex table-process-warning">

            <div class="table-thead ">
                <div class="table-row table-header">
                    <div class="table-row-item">
                        <h3 class="table-title"><a href="#" class="btn btn-default main-menu-toggle"><i class="icon fa fa-bars"></i></a> Warning processes</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.table-row -->
                <div class="table-row">
                    <div class="table-row-item flex-grow-4">Context</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item flex-grow-4">Process Session</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item flex-grow-3">Execution</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item flex-grow-1">Info</div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.table-row -->
                <div class="table-row">
                    <div class="table-row-item">Process ID</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">Source</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">Schedule</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">Context</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">Session ID</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">Period From</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">Period To</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">Action</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">Start</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">End</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">Duration</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">Status message</div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.table-row -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.table-thead -->

            <div class="table-tbody">

                <div class="table-row">
                    <div class="table-row-item">PROCID123</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">N/A</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">DAY</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">DEV</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">6</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">27.9.2017</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">28.9.2017</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item"><input type="checkbox"></div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">13.10.2017 00:00</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">13.10.2017 01:58</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">00:01:58</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus, dolor!</div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.table-row -->
                <div class="table-row">
                    <div class="table-row-item">PROCID123</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">N/A</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">DAY</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">DEV</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">6</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">27.9.2017</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">28.9.2017</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item"><input type="checkbox"></div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">13.10.2017 00:00</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">13.10.2017 01:58</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">00:01:58</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus, dolor!</div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.table-row -->
                <div class="table-row">
                    <div class="table-row-item">PROCID123</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">N/A</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">DAY</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">DEV</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">6</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">27.9.2017</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">28.9.2017</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item"><input type="checkbox"></div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">13.10.2017 00:00</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">13.10.2017 01:58</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">00:01:58</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus, dolor!</div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.table-row -->
                <div class="table-row">
                    <div class="table-row-item">PROCID123</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">N/A</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">DAY</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">DEV</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">6</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">27.9.2017</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">28.9.2017</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item"><input type="checkbox"></div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">13.10.2017 00:00</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">13.10.2017 01:58</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">00:01:58</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus, dolor!</div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.table-row -->
                <div class="table-row">
                    <div class="table-row-item">PROCID123</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">N/A</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">DAY</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">DEV</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">6</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">27.9.2017</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">28.9.2017</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item"><input type="checkbox"></div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">13.10.2017 00:00</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">13.10.2017 01:58</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">00:01:58</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus, dolor!</div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.table-row -->
                <div class="table-row">
                    <div class="table-row-item">PROCID123</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">N/A</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">DAY</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">DEV</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">6</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">27.9.2017</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">28.9.2017</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item"><input type="checkbox"></div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">13.10.2017 00:00</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">13.10.2017 01:58</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">00:01:58</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus, dolor!</div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.table-row -->
                <div class="table-row">
                    <div class="table-row-item">PROCID123</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">N/A</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">DAY</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">DEV</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">6</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">27.9.2017</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">28.9.2017</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item"><input type="checkbox"></div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">13.10.2017 00:00</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">13.10.2017 01:58</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">00:01:58</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus, dolor!</div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.table-row -->
                <div class="table-row">
                    <div class="table-row-item">PROCID123</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">N/A</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">DAY</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">DEV</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">6</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">27.9.2017</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">28.9.2017</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item"><input type="checkbox"></div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">13.10.2017 00:00</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">13.10.2017 01:58</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">00:01:58</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus, dolor!</div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.table-row -->
                <div class="table-row">
                    <div class="table-row-item">PROCID123</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">N/A</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">DAY</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">DEV</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">6</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">27.9.2017</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">28.9.2017</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item"><input type="checkbox"></div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">13.10.2017 00:00</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">13.10.2017 01:58</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">00:01:58</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus, dolor!</div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.table-row -->
                <div class="table-row">
                    <div class="table-row-item">PROCID123</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">N/A</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">DAY</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">DEV</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">6</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">27.9.2017</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">28.9.2017</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item"><input type="checkbox"></div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">13.10.2017 00:00</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">13.10.2017 01:58</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">00:01:58</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus, dolor!</div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.table-row -->

            </div>
            <!-- /.table-tbody -->

        </div>
        <!-- /.table-flex -->
        <div class="table-flex table-process-running">

            <div class="table-thead ">
                <div class="table-row table-header">
                    <div class="table-row-item">
                        <h3 class="table-title"><a href="#" class="btn btn-default main-menu-toggle"><i class="icon fa fa-bars"></i></a> Running processes</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.table-row -->
                <div class="table-row">
                    <div class="table-row-item flex-grow-4">Context</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item flex-grow-4">Process Session</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item flex-grow-3">Execution</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item flex-grow-1">Info</div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.table-row -->
                <div class="table-row">
                    <div class="table-row-item">Process ID</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">Source</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">Schedule</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">Context</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">Session ID</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">Period From</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">Period To</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">Action</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">Start</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">End</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">Duration</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">Status message</div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.table-row -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.table-thead -->

            <div class="table-tbody">

                <div class="table-row">
                    <div class="table-row-item">PROCID123</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">N/A</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">DAY</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">DEV</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">6</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">27.9.2017</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">28.9.2017</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item"><input type="checkbox"></div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">13.10.2017 00:00</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">13.10.2017 01:58</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">00:01:58</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus, dolor!</div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.table-row -->
                <div class="table-row">
                    <div class="table-row-item">PROCID123</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">N/A</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">DAY</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">DEV</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">6</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">27.9.2017</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">28.9.2017</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item"><input type="checkbox"></div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">13.10.2017 00:00</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">13.10.2017 01:58</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">00:01:58</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus, dolor!</div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.table-row -->
                <div class="table-row">
                    <div class="table-row-item">PROCID123</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">N/A</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">DAY</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">DEV</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">6</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">27.9.2017</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">28.9.2017</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item"><input type="checkbox"></div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">13.10.2017 00:00</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">13.10.2017 01:58</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">00:01:58</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus, dolor!</div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.table-row -->
                <div class="table-row">
                    <div class="table-row-item">PROCID123</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">N/A</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">DAY</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">DEV</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">6</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">27.9.2017</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">28.9.2017</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item"><input type="checkbox"></div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">13.10.2017 00:00</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">13.10.2017 01:58</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">00:01:58</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus, dolor!</div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.table-row -->
                <div class="table-row">
                    <div class="table-row-item">PROCID123</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">N/A</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">DAY</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">DEV</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">6</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">27.9.2017</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">28.9.2017</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item"><input type="checkbox"></div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">13.10.2017 00:00</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">13.10.2017 01:58</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">00:01:58</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus, dolor!</div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.table-row -->
                <div class="table-row">
                    <div class="table-row-item">PROCID123</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">N/A</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">DAY</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">DEV</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">6</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">27.9.2017</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">28.9.2017</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item"><input type="checkbox"></div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">13.10.2017 00:00</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">13.10.2017 01:58</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">00:01:58</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus, dolor!</div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.table-row -->
                <div class="table-row">
                    <div class="table-row-item">PROCID123</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">N/A</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">DAY</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">DEV</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">6</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">27.9.2017</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">28.9.2017</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item"><input type="checkbox"></div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">13.10.2017 00:00</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">13.10.2017 01:58</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">00:01:58</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus, dolor!</div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.table-row -->
                <div class="table-row">
                    <div class="table-row-item">PROCID123</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">N/A</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">DAY</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">DEV</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">6</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">27.9.2017</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">28.9.2017</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item"><input type="checkbox"></div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">13.10.2017 00:00</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">13.10.2017 01:58</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">00:01:58</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus, dolor!</div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.table-row -->
                <div class="table-row">
                    <div class="table-row-item">PROCID123</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">N/A</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">DAY</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">DEV</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">6</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">27.9.2017</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">28.9.2017</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item"><input type="checkbox"></div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">13.10.2017 00:00</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">13.10.2017 01:58</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">00:01:58</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus, dolor!</div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.table-row -->
                <div class="table-row">
                    <div class="table-row-item">PROCID123</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">N/A</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">DAY</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">DEV</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">6</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">27.9.2017</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">28.9.2017</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item"><input type="checkbox"></div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">13.10.2017 00:00</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">13.10.2017 01:58</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">00:01:58</div>
                    <div class="table-row-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus, dolor!</div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.table-row -->

            </div>
            <!-- /.table-tbody -->

        </div>
        <!-- /.table-flex -->

    </div>
    <!-- /.content -->
</div>
<!-- /.container-fluid -->
```

**SCSS**

```
// Functions
@function grey($shade) {
  @if not map-has-key($grey, $shade) {
    @warn "Color #{$shade} not found in $grey map.";
  }
  @return map-get($grey, $shade);
}

// Colors
$grey: (
  lightest: #f6f6f6, 
  light: #dedede, 
  dark: #afafaf, 
  darkest: #777777
);
$white: #ffffff;

// Animations
@mixin transition {
  transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

// Text overflow
%text-overflow {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  // vertical-align: top;
}

// Main menu
.main-menu {
  position: fixed;
  overflow-y: auto;
  left: 0;
}

// Container
.content {
  @include transition;
  margin-left: 0;
  .main-menu-open & {
    margin-left: 300px;
  }
}

// Tables
.table-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid grey(dark);
}
.table-thead {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  .table-row-item {
    background-color: grey(light);
  }
}
.table-row {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}
.table-row-item {
  @extend %text-overflow;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
  background-color: grey(lightest);
  border-right: 2px solid $white;
  border-bottom: 2px solid $white;
  padding: 8px;

  // Flex grow
  @for $i from 1 through 6 {
    $grow: $i * 1;
    &.flex-grow-#{$i} {
      flex: $grow calc(100% / (12/#{$i}));
    }
  }
}
```

**JS (menu toggle)**

```
$('.main-menu-toggle').click(function(e) {
    $('body').toggleClass('main-menu-open');
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

Comment: You should post a _minimal_ working code snippet reproducing the issue _within_ the question. Read more here how to ask: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I had to put as many table rows as it was needed for sticky to work, and to be able to scroll, therefore almost all the code was needed. And for the character limit of 30 000, I had to delete more than half since I had 63 000.
Code is now posted in the question... Thanks for the info!